# What does "fully wired" mean when buying a PSU?

Tags: desktop, power-supply

The following power supply units on Ebuyer are described as being "fully wired".

[Ace Black 120mm Fan 550W Fully Wired Efficient Power Supply](http://www.ebuyer.com/566862-ace-black-120mm-fan-550w-fully-wired-efficient-power-supply-psuace550br)

[CIT 450W Fully Wired Efficient Power Supply](http://www.ebuyer.com/159705-cit-450w-fully-wired-efficient-power-supply-psucit450ub)

[PowerCool 850W Fully Wired 80+ Power Supply](http://www.ebuyer.com/151296-powercool-850w-fully-wired-80-power-supply-pc850aubab)

[CIT Dual Rail 480W Fully Wired Efficient Power Supply](http://www.ebuyer.com/158481-cit-dual-rail-480w-fully-wired-efficient-power-supply-480ub)

Searching Google for what exactly this means brings up results for modular PSUs, but [this PSU here](http://www.ebuyer.com/621475-builder-500w-fully-wired-efficient-power-supply-psu500builderblack) is described as being "fully wired" while also not being modular at all.

The only thing I can think of that "fully wired" would describe would be a PSU that comes wired, but to me that seems about as odd a selling point as a car that comes with wheels. :-)

**When buying a PSU, what exactly does "fully wired" mean?**

Comment: Is this qualified as  a question? It's not exactly asking for a specific hardware recomendation. Good question though. I upvoted. I just want to know if this is the kind of question.

Comment: @Jim Whilst the OP is not asking for a specific hardware recommendation, an answer to his question will at least help him to make an informed decision.

Comment: Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on Super User.

Comment: Don't be silly, @Jeff. As demonstrated in the question, it's common for sites to include this descriptor with their products, and nowhere else documents it. Knowing what exactly it means, as Mick said, can only contribute to helping people make informed decisions about their hardware purchases, and it's nowhere near technical support. If this site is going to adopt such a myopic view of what constitutes questions on hardware I can only see it being so popular. That's a level of pedantry only the SOFU sites can afford, because they made the bulk of their userbase without it a long time ago.

Comment: @Hashim  Unfortunately. there is nothing in your questions that refers to a recommendation.  Per the site guidelines this is a Technical Supports questions.  If the post was worded differently IE: I am looking for a power supply for my computer.  I am seeing options of XX and XX.  Would you recommend a Fully Wired or Modular.  Etc.  I know it is all semantics but this site could EASILY turn into a tech support forum. On a side note your post was well formed.  Just definitely for what you are asking fits on SU.

Comment: And we all know [how those turn out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQh56geU0X8)...

Comment: For a definitive opinion as to whether this question is on-topic, see my question on [meta](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/613/should-questions-that-help-users-to-make-informed-decisions-be-allowed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fully-wired PSU is simply a non-modular PSU, and comes with all power cables hard-wired. A semi-modular PSU has the essential cables hard wired and the other cables socketed. A (fully) modular PSU has all power cables socketed. To quote Overclockers:

> Whereas non-modular power supplies come with all possible cables already attached, a modular PSU comes with connectors, giving you the freedom to use only the cables that you really need. There are two types of modular PSU, and the one you decide to go for will largely depend on your requirements and budget. A semi modular PSU comes with only the essential cables wired on—usually the ATX 12V and EPS 12V, and in some cases the PCI-E cables—whilst a fully modular PSU comes with no cables whatsoever. A semi modular power supply offers a more affordable solution, whilst a fully modular power supply allows for ultimate cable flexibility at a somewhat higher price point.

**[www.overclockers.co.uk](https://www.overclockers.co.uk/pc-components/power-supplies/modular)**